# do i have to add the web api config code in all my javascript file in my project?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Do I need to add the firebase web API code in all my javascript files in my project? When I used it on the first page it was working.Now I put it on the second page, firebase code not working.

This is the index page code, it's working.

```
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyAPlhWdY7OVAEI_LrGMP073D5Ra6g",
authDomain: "mgf.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://mgf.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "mgf",
storageBucket: "mgf.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "579064514788"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


function login()
{var pass;
var database = firebase.database();
var dbref=database.ref();
dbref.child('Admin').child('AdminName').once('value', snap=>
{
if(document.getElementById('txtan').value==snap.val()){
    dbref.child('Admin').child('password').once('value', snap=>
    {
        if(document.getElementById('txtap').value==snap.val())
            window.location = 'dashboard.html';
        else
            alert('invalid login');
});}
else{alert('invalid login');}
});
}
```

This is the second page code,not working

```
    var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAPlhWdY7OVAEI_LrGMP073D5Ra6g",
    authDomain: "mgf.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mgf.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "mgf",
    storageBucket: "mgf.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "579064514788"
    };
   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   function addofficer()
   {
var e = document.getElementById("depto");
var dept = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if(document.getElementById('radiom').checked=true){
var gender=document.getElementById('radiom').value;}
else{
var gender=document.getElementById('radiof').value;}
var uid=document.getElementById('uido').value;
var email=document.getElementById('emailo').value;
var pass=document.getElementById('passo').value;
var dob=document.getElementById('dobo').value;
var name=document.getElementById('nameo').value;
var mobile=document.getElementById('mobo').value;
var house=document.getElementById('houseo').value;
var street=document.getElementById('streeto').value;
var areaa=document.getElementById('areao').value;
var post=document.getElementById('pofco').value;
var vtc=document.getElementById('vtco').value;
var dist=document.getElementById('dsto').value;
var pin=document.getElementById('pco').value;

}
```

Do i have to add the firebase initialize code again in the second file?

Comment: Make sure you have also added the firebase scripts to the second html file

Comment: it worked when i remove those form that from the code